# -scp option not working properly with gp.exe

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I have two commands that expected to behave the same:

```
gp -key-enc 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -key-kek 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -key-mac 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -mode mac keyid 0 keyver 0 -sdaid A000000151000000 -debug -list
gp -key-enc 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -key-kek 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -key-mac 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -mode mac -scp 2 keyid 0 keyver 0 -sdaid A000000151000000 -debug -list
```

The only difference is the addition of "-scp 2" in the second command.
The card clearly supports scp 02.
The options are explicitly stated.

The first command is okay in external authentication.
The second command is not okay in external authentication (0x6982).

I am using GlobalPlatformPro v0.3.9 from [GitHub](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/releases)! that supports SCP03.
It should support SCP01, 02 and 03.

I need to understand what could be the issue I am encountering right now.
I tried some proprietary tools and it works perfectly but I need to make it work here in GlobalPlatformPro.
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide an APDU trace for both commands?

Comment: Which card? Are you sure that the default key set is the only one installed? And are you sure that the default key set is 40...4F?

Comment: Hi Maarten, I specified the keyset and keyversion explicitly. I think this is a bug in the tool